# Can't run Java example for Selenium / WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Having a problem getting going with Selenium on Java.  I'm trying to follow the example on this page:  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

I'm typing this:

```
$ javac -cp . -cp ~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0-srcs.jar -cp ~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar -g Example.java
```

And getting this:

```
alis-mac-pro:selenium ali$ java ExampleException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Example (wrong name: org/openqa/selenium/example/Example)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I pasted the code from the example into Example.java.

UPDATE

---

A kind soul on #java at irc.freenode.net told me to chain my entries in the classpath.  So, instead of:

```
$ javac -cp . -cp ~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0-srcs.jar -cp ~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar -g Example.java
```

I used:

```
javac -cp .:~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0-srcs.jar:~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar -g Example.java
```

Great!  :-)  But now new errors:

```
Example.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class By
location: package org.openqa.selenium
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                          ^
Example.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WebDriver
location: package org.openqa.selenium
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
Example.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WebElement
location: package org.openqa.selenium
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
                          ^
Example.java:6: package org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
                                   ^
Example.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WebDriver
location: class org.openqa.selenium.example.Example
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        ^
Example.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HtmlUnitDriver
location: class org.openqa.selenium.example.Example
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
                               ^
Example.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WebElement
location: class org.openqa.selenium.example.Example
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        ^
Example.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable By
location: class org.openqa.selenium.example.Example
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
                                                ^
8 errors
```

UPDATE

---

I tried:

```
$ jar tf ~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar
```

But I see the org.openqa.selenium.By class, for example, so it doesn't appear that I'm missing any packages.

UPDATE

---

Okay!  :-)  I removed the package specifier.  I executed:

```
$ javac -classpath ~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar Example.java
```

Which is what a commenter gave me, except I added the full path to the .jar.  Then I executed:

```
$ java -cp .:~/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar Example
```

Which gave me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

UPDATE

---

Hurray!  Victory, thanks to Mike Kwan.  The following is what worked:

```
alis-mac-pro:selenium ali$ javac -cp ".:/Users/ali/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar:/Users/ali/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0-srcs.jar:/Users/ali/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/libs/*" Example.java
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
alis-mac-pro:selenium ali$ java -cp ".:/Users/ali/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0.jar:/Users/ali/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/selenium-java-2.20.0-srcs.jar:/Users/ali/Downloads/selenium-2.20.0/libs/*" Example
Page title is: Cheese! - Google Search
```

BTW, I added the last part of the "-cp" option (for "libs/*"), because that's where HTMLUnit was when I downloaded the Selenium / WebDriver stuff.

Comment: I think your "Example.class" file is in the wrong directory, it should be in the org.openqa.selenium.example one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compile like so:

```
javac -classpath selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar Example.java
```

Unless you put the Java file in the `org.openqa.selenium.example`, you will have to remove the package specifier. Run the compiled file like so:

```
java -cp .:selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar Example
```

This chains the current directory to the classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!  I updated my question with the results.

Comment: Try to use the full path instead of the ~

Comment: Mike, why would the authors of the example code give a package specifier in this case?

Comment: Because it's good practice to use packages. In this case, with only one source file it's not necessary. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Answer (score 2):

For those doing a java dynamic web project in eclipse, and receiving the error above, the following link might help:

http://me-ol-blog.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/using-selenium-in-java-dynamic-web.html

Basically, it mentions that the standalone jar is not "standalone" when using dynamic web projects and that a different jar should be used along with its dependent jars.

Answer (score 0):

Add html unit driver dependency in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

It is working fine for me.