# unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar

In the directory `C:\jars>` In the Jars folder I have Test folder. Inside the Test folder I have `OneReports.jar` ,`testng.jar`, `TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java` and `Test.XML`

The `OneReports.jar` I have exported from eclipse and it contains a few java Projects.

The `Test.xml` I have created testsuite and that file is

In the command Prompt I tried to run:

1. C:\Jars>javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium*.jar";"OneReports.jar";"testng
   .jar" test\TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java
2. C:\Jars>java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium*.jar";"OneReports.jar";"testng.
   jar" test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML

Here I got error as follows:

```
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class test.LoginOneReports - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1289)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.main(TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more

 C:\Jars>
```

Could any one please help me to fix the issue. I'm not using maven. Using Selenium webdriver, TestNG, Java for writing code.

Comment: Can you specify the exact names of the `selenium*.jar` files that you have under `C:\Program Files\Java`?

Comment: yes C:\Program Files\Java\selenium.. Inside this selenium folder i have all the jar files which i added as referenced libraries in eclipse. i have **commons-io-2.4,selenium-java-2.39.0, selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0, log4j-1.2.17, commons-io-2.4-sources, commons-io-2.4-tests, commons-io-2.4-test-sources, selenium-java-2.39.0-srcs** jar files

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\selenium`??? This is a separate folder? If yes, then you should change your class-path to `"C:\Program Files\Java\selenium\*.jar"` (add a backslash after `"selenium"`).

Comment: yes i added a back slash and tried still I'm facing the issue

Comment: How about using the exact name of each JAR file? For Selenium, you only need two of them: `selenium-java-2.39.0` and `selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0`.

Comment: you ever think about using Maven? If you use Maven, this classpath stuff will go right out the window.

Comment: Can you get it to run from within eclipse? That might be the easiest way to check you have everything needed in the classpath. I'm also suspicious about the wildcard expansion. Javac is expecting entries to be separated by ; I'm not sure thats what the expansion will give. You may find it easier to put things in a .bat batch file that makes it much easier to specify very long classpath lines.

Comment: Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057163/cant-run-java-example-for-selenium-webdriver You have at least same error than there, maybe you can see that and come up with correct command.

Comment: Another possibility is to use ant and for that [this tutorial](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.in/2011/10/executing-selenium-testng-tests-using.html) has a solution where your code is on half way in the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your javac worked, you  have testng.jar  in the classpath correctly.  Then the program has dependency on other libraries selenium etc.  It will be correct to use individual jars instead of wild cards.

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium<version>.jar;OneReports.jar;testng.jar" test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
```

This may give more classnotfound exception. Add only those to your classpath.

Note that you are referring other jars too by relative path (OneReports.jar or testng.jar). This can get pretty messy.  Consider using ant/maven/gradle to do this part of the work. They would form the classpath more reliably.