# Selenium Webdriver Example issue

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to follow along with the examples found on https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted but I'm running into an issue with the package `org.openqa.selenium.example` being "incorrect". The rest of the code seems to be ok with the exception of the `public class Example` also having a red dot saying it needs to be declared, but I figured this is because the above package is having issues.

When I run the code, this is the out put:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test.Test
/Users/me/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I know there is a similar thread found here :[Can't run Java example for Selenium / WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057163/cant-run-java-example-for-selenium-webdriver), but with this being my first go at using both Java and Selenium, I'm still having a hard time trouble shooting this issue. In case you don't want to follow the link to the example, here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm able to run this code. I got this output "Page title is: Cheese! - Google Search"

Comment: Hmm, what steps did you take? It seems almost like the Example.jar does not exist for me, as I am unable to find it in the `Selenium-server-standalone.jar` that I downloaded with the tutorial. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you compiling it from cmd prompt or ide ???  I didn't add any Example.jar in the class path except selenium dependencies

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE and I've already added the Selenium jar files to the PATHCLASS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans.  I use eclipse.  As said by TJames,  add the project directory and dependency screenshot.  It might help me to figure out the issue.

Comment: Updated with screenshot. This is my first time using NetBeans, so I'm not very familiar with it either

Comment: Ahh..! Can you refactor the src package to **org.openqa.selenium.example**? You can right click on the example package and refactor it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98457/discussion-between-harshavmb-and-jcmoney1010).

Comment: lol I think it worked! Output provided a ton of CSS error warnings, but at the end produced `Page title is: Chease! - Google Search`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your src package containing .java class is wrong. It should be **org.openqa.selenium.example** rather **example**. As the package declared inside class is not same as package declared outside. It threw a compile time error. Refactoring packaging to  **org.openqa.selenium.example** outside in the src package or editing the **org.openqa.selenium.example** to **example** should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The package declaration is the package that your class Example is supposed to be in.  It has to match the directory that your code is in, or else it won't compile.

**Solution 1:** Put your Example.java file should be in a directory like this:

`[directory-to-your-project-root-or-source-folder]/org/openqa/selenium/example`

**Solution 2:** Assuming your Example.java is already sitting directly in the root folder of your project, you can just remove the package declaration from the top of your Example.java file.

**Solution 3:**  Declare your own package, like `package com.jcmoney.example;`, and then create a matching directory in your project `com/jcmoney/example` and put your Example.java file in it.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments below and the screenshot added to the question:

[image: Project Structure]

See how it says "Source Packages", and below it "example" and then below it "Example.java"?  Example.java is the file that your code is in.  It is in the package "example".

So, **quickest solution**:  Change your package declaration from "org.openqa.selenium.example" to just "example".

Comment: Well that seems to be part of the issue, I can't seem to find this `Example.jar` file. I figured it would be in the `selenium-see-standalone-2` file that I downloaded, but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Not `Example.jar`, `Example.java`.  `Example.java` is the file with the code in it that you pasted above in your question.  Or at least it should be.  What **is** the name of the file that you've put Example class code in?  If it's not named `Example.java`, then we've got more problems.

Comment: That was my mistake, I mistyped `.jar` instead of `.java` when replaying to both your post and the comment above. I have been unable to locate the `Example.java` file. When I take the package declaration away from the top, it brings up a red bubble saying `class, interface, enum expected`

Comment: That is weird.  What IDE are you using?  Eclipse?  Whichever it is, can you add a screenshot of your project directory to your question?

Comment: I've updated with a screen shot, I'm using NetBeans, and I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: Updated answer.  Also, I'd personally recommend Eclipse over NetBeans, since you're not familiar with either one yet, you might as well get familiar with the more widely used one (Eclipse).

Comment: @harshavmb pointed out the same issue, and suggested I change the name to `org.openqa.selenium.example`. Once I did this, I was able to compile the code. I wish there was a way I could give both of you a green check mark! Lastly, I'll take a look at Eclipse, thanks for the advice.