# Selenium Inaccuracy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, browser-automation

I've just started working with selenium, and I followed the steps here to get started, however, when I run the example given on the page:

```java
public class Testface {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object WebDriver;
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    }

}
```

Errors:
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class WebDriver
location: class Testface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run Java example for Selenium / WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057163/cant-run-java-example-for-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the `import` in your `code`. To solve this issue you have to add the below `import` in the top of your given `code`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

Also, make sure that you have added the `Selenium WebDriver` dependency in your project. In case of maven in your pom.xml file or add the `jar` `file` if you are using a different build tool.